# What is the difference between normal and perpendicular, orthogonal and tangent to the surface?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

What is the difference between normal and perpendicular, orthogonal and tangent to the surface?

Does a normal means a unit vector to the surface? is there any difference when we use the words normal and perpendicular when talking about the surface?

Comment: Well, "tangent" means something very different.  For a circle in the plane, say, a "normal" is given by the radial vector.  The tangent is perpendicular to that.

Comment: okay, is there any difference between normal and perpendicular to the surface?

Comment: A "normal vector" is perpendicular and of length $1$. And usually oriented towards the outside of the surface, if applicable. So normal implies perpendicular, but the converse may not hold.

Comment: Not really, though if you are speaking of a fixed vector I think it would be more standard to call it a "a normal vector".  To be clear though:  just saying that, e.g., $\vec n$ is normal to a surface does not tell you about the length of $\vec n$.  If you want length $1$ you can refer to a "unit normal".

Comment: @user3257842  I don't think it's universal practice to require a "normal vector" to have length $1$.  [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalVector.html) for instance, it is clearly spelled out that if you want length $1$ you generally need to rescale.

Comment: Okay, thanks. So normal to the surface is a special case of perpendicular where the length of the vector is constant, right?

Comment: Again, no.  My (strong) belief is that just specifying "normal" tells you nothing about the length (well, I'd take it to mean non-zero length).  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) is another reference making it clear that the length is not specified.  and what do you mean by "constant"?  It's just one vector, right?  It's length is its length.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

As we have a tangent for a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ i.e., a line which touches the curve at that point (and tells direction of the curve at that point), similarly for a surface we have the tangent plane which just touches the surface at the point and is parallel to the surface at that point.
Now we can talk about the perpendicular to this tangent at that point on the surface. Normal vector, orthogonal vector are just different names for perpendicular in this context.